# Error occurred when run program packed by py2exe

Tags: pyqt4, py2exe

I packed a python program (involving PyQT4) with py2exe, the exe file run normally on my  machine, but when i copy it to another machine, error occurred like following (in log file):

> File "PyQt4\QtGui.pyc", line 12, in
>      File "PyQt4\QtGui.pyc",
>   line 10, in __load ImportError: DLL
>   load failed:

**more details:**

- i am using Python 2.5.
- MSVCR71.dll is available in the same directorywith the exe file.

**my setup.py script:**

```
# coding: utf-8

from distutils.core import setup

import py2exe

import sys



#this allows to run it with a simple double click.

sys.argv.append('py2exe')


script = [{

    "script":"test.py", 

    'icon_resources':[(0, 'main.ico'),]

    }]



py2exe_options = {

        "includes":["sip",],

        "dll_excludes": ["MSVCP90.dll",]

        }

setup(windows=script, options={'py2exe':py2exe_options})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to distribute the pyqt4 dlls with your exe for it to run on computers where pyqt4 is not installed. You should be able to find the dlls in something like C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\bin

To package the dlls with your exe you can use an installer like [nsis](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/) or [inno](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php).

Comment: Even i copy all the dll in the "PyQt4\bin" into the same directory with the exe file, also has this problem.

Comment: which dll does it say is missing? - the error message is cut off.

Comment: After i installed the dotnet frame, everything is ok now.

Comment: what is the dotnet frame? .NET?

Comment: yes, .NET   http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/0/e/20e90413-712f-438c-988e-fdaa79a8ac3d/dotnetfx35.exe